# ATG Log rotation

Tags: logging, atg, atg-dynamo

I need to override the server logs rotation policy used by ATG for rolling up and archiving the server logs everyday. I went to the atg.nucleus.logging.RotatingFileLogger.schedule property in dyn/admin of my page server and updated it,

> schedule=calendar * * . * 0 0

But it seems that the policy is not overriding, I don't get, is there any other property file? Am I doing it wrong?
Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your schedule is set to CalendarSchedule.

```
schedule=CalendarSchedule
```

Secondly, you are using the newer 6 parameter schedule (older versions used 5), which is good, but I think you want:

```
schedule=calendar * * * * 0 0
```

I believe this is correct as the `cron` syntax would be "0 0 * * * *".